# Java Swing List get parameter object type

Tags: java, list, swing, jcombobox

I'm just starting with Java coding and actually try create  simply application in swing - with two comboBox field, containing multiple column (each combo has other List).

I study solution presented on stackoverflow and create code below. It's working, but only on one type of List. I want create more universal code, to handle  in one Class, more than one List type.
Could I get type of List and handle in one Class two different ComboBox List, or I must search other options to do this. 
I very thankful to give me advise, or give the better solution (maybe I thing wrong and it's the better solution to do this).

My Code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class MyComboBox extends JComboBox {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyComboBox(List<?> list) {
        super(list.toArray());

        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            this.setRenderer(new ComboCustomRender());

        }

    }

    private class ComboCustomRender extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            Foo foo = (Foo) value;
            label.setText(foo.getField1() + foo.getField2);
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your renderer handles elements of type Foo. Why would you use the same class to handle other types of elements. Creating another class would be much cleaner: there is no reason to use the same class to use two different things. You should also avoid extending JComboBox. It's useless. Just use one.

Comment: In my code render handles is type of Foo, but I want

Comment: In my code - render handles is type of Foo, but I want use universal type example other type Foo2 - when in JCombobox use List with Foo then cast to Foo, when Foo2 then cast to Foo2. I just starting with Java, maybe i don't understand all basic conception so i be thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understood my mistake and found the solution to do this.
I don't need a class extends JComboBox, but only Class with implementation getListCellRendererComponent(), where i can wrote class to handle each type of List.
Second solution is override method toString() in each class which I use in list and then don't need to cast object - olny return method toString().